# How to define a Class method like MyObject[:test]= 'test'

Tags: ruby

This is what I want do create, but it doesnt work:

```
class MyObject
   def self.[]=(key, value)
     @@internal_hash[key] = value 
   end
end
```

I don't understand why overriding the self dot bracket doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? That works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the class variable.

```
class MyObject
  @@internal_hash = {}
  def self.[]=(key, value)
    @@internal_hash[key] = value 
  end
end
```

This is for two reasons.

1. Instance variables can be used without initialization, but class variables cannot.[Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html):Class Variables and Class Methods:Class Variables:1st paragraph
2. Even if a class variable was able to be used without initialization, it would be implicitly initialized to `nil`, and you cannot suddenly use the `Hash#[]` method.

Comment: class variables can be used without initialization.

Comment: @Rein Can you give an example of calling a class variable without initializing it?

Comment: Wow. Apparently I am a liar. Apologies. I don't think I've used a class variable in years.